# Does open-layers support ESM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, vite, openlayers

I switched my project that uses open layers from react16, node14, and webpack to use react18, node18, and vite.

With this change, I am getting the following error within featureLoader.

I am also using esm now instead of converting everything to commonjs, which i am wondering could be the problem

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at loadFeaturesXhr (featureloader.js:69:7)
    at VectorSource2.loader_ (featureloader.js:148:5)
    at _loop_1 (Vector.js:992:22)
    at VectorSource2.loadFeatures (Vector.js:975:59)
    at CanvasVectorLayerRenderer2.prepareFrame (VectorLayer.js:673:22)
    at Layer2.render (Layer.js:279:23)
    at CompositeMapRenderer2.renderFrame (Composite.js:123:29)
    at PluggableMap2.renderFrame_ (PluggableMap.js:1553:7)
    at Map2.<anonymous> (PluggableMap.js:260:12)
```

I appreciate any insight or direction on this issue. thanks!

Comment: Would you please provide a reproducible example to try? The error message shows a general case that does not help your specific situation. Similar issues, with the same error, could be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+convert+object+to+primitive+value

Comment: Not sure how I could do that, the error is happening within the open-layers and doesn't seem to be coming from my end.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `featureloader.js:69` and check what is this object